# What is meant by 'fixing' of an antigen presenting cell?

Tags: immunology, antigen, mhc

Can someone please explain what does 'fixing' of an antigen presenting cell mean?

Comment: In which context did you find this term?

Comment: in the chapter of MHC and APC (Kuby).

Comment: You can also read about purpose and the procedure of hostological fixation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(histology)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10593509/), fixation of an antigen presenting cell refers to the exposure of antigen presenting cells to paraformaldehyde prior to immunostaining. This treatment is used to aggregate membrane proteins and strengthen the intercellular transient protein-protein interaction.

Resource

Barisas BG, Wade WF, Jovin TM, Arndt-Jovin D, Roess DA. Dynamics of molecules involved in antigen presentation: effects of fixation. Mol Immunol. 1999 Aug;36(11-12):701-8. doi: 10.1016/s0161-5890(99)00091-7. PMID: 10593509.